# Retrieving results without submit

Tags: asp.net, ajax

just like in google, when you search for something.
the websites are displayed without clicking submit button.

how do you achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Learn javascript
2. Learn ajax
3. Learn how to use JQuery + some google to find out how to integrete Jquery in your programming language

How i learned it:

**Resources on javascript :**

- Site : [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)
- Book : Head first javascript

**Resources on Ajax :**

- Book : Head first ajax

**Resources on Jquery :**

Google google google ! and tons of reading on blogs. But the sites you will cross the most :

1. http://jquery.com/
2. For some magic : http://jqueryui.com/

also keep in mind that using javascript can be database-intensive so cache your results.

The answer on your question: http://flux88.com/blog/jquery-auto-complete-text-box-with-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value of an input at any time using javascript. I suggest you learn [jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery#Rate_me%3a_Using_Ajax) if you want to make ajax applications.

```
// show the value of the html element with id 'nameInput'
alert($('nameInput').value);
```